# How to set up 2 different Jenkins jobs linked with 2 different repos in one Jenkins installation?

Tags: github, jenkins

I have Job1 that is linked to a Github repo and when I push code it builds in it's own workspace (space1)

I want to add a second job (Job2) that will be linked with a different GitHub repo and will build the code in a different workspace (space2).

**Notice**: *2 different jobs building different code from different repos (both master branches) in different workspaces.*

Is it possible with vanilla Jenkins or will I need any extra plugin?

I have researched Pipeline ([link1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin), [link2](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/)) a little but I try to figure out if it covers my use case.

**EDIT:**

I have setup the communication between the second job and GitHub but in order for the build to succeed needs an SSH key. But Jenkins provides only one slot for configuring the SSH key.

[image]

Also I have added a second workspace .

[image]

Comment: Are you just asking how to set up two jobs on one Jenkins installation? This is what Jenkins does.

Comment: No,I have set up the two jobs and linked them with the two different repos. But I should add a workspace and SSH key for the second one and I don't know if/how it is possible. And I cannot find any kind of such documentation